# ListBox установка модели в качестве ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте, у меня есть модель, скажем

```
public partial class ClientInfoModel : DependencyObject
{
    public int clientId
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(clientIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(clientIdProperty, value); Console.WriteLine("Set {0}", value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty clientIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("clientId", typeof(int), typeof(ClientInfoModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Так же есть UserControl для её отображения, который содержит в себе свойство Model с ссылкой на модель.

Как можно обернуть модели в ListBox, при этом не создавать обёртку из UserControl'а, т.е указать в ListBox.ItemsSource модели, а в списке получить UserControl'ы?

Дело в том, что решить вопрос установкой DataContext = ModelContext у контрола не получится, т.к он содержит еще и собственные свойства.

Comment: Переопределите свойство 'itemtemplate' у 'listbox'.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено.
Скажем у нас есть модель и её вью-модель с собственными свойствами, тем временем модель лежит в свойстве Model, тогда при использовании вью-модели в списках можно установить свойство Model = DataContext as IamModel; после события Loaded.

```
public class IamModel : DependencyObject{
  /* различные свойства */
}

public class IamViewModel : UserControl {
  public IamModel Model { get; set; }

  //собственное свойство, которого нет в модели
  public string AnotherProp { get; set; }

  /*
  установим модель из DataContext который передаёт нам WPF, 
  например из ListBox
  */
  public IamViewModel(){
    Loaded += (sender, args) => {
      Model = DataContext as IamModel;
      DataContext = this;
    }
  }
}
```

Данный подход позволит нам избежать наследования ViewModel от Model, при этом даст возможность использовать в разметке все свойства модели и вью-модели, а так же возможность использовать вью-модель как элемент списка

Comment: Я не понимаю как вы с такими моделями унаследованными от DependencyObject потом работаете с БД. И как вообще у вас не идет кругом голова от спагеттикода этих моделей, а последнее на мой взгляд совсем фееричное `Model = DataContext as IamModel; DataContext = this;`. И это работает? Не, правда что-ли? Неужели нет циклической ссылки? И как можно наследовать ViewModel от UserControl? UserControl - это же чистое View. Как можно ViewModel превращать во View одним легким движением пальцев по клавиатуре?